# Use Lodash to compare, match and filter two objects

Tags: javascript, json, object, lodash

I have one object that looks like this (with a nested object):

```
var data = {
"results":{  
           "Description":"There was a record added",
           "resultTimestamp":"2017-03-23T21:56:05Z"
        },
"service":"FDSY",
"StartTimestamp":"2017-03-23T21:55:17Z",
"eventId":"033dc019-0b8a-4af22",
"assetId":"TenGigE0/14/0/0.55",
"assetType":"CLCI" 
}
```

and another that looks like this (also with a nested object):

```
var filter = {
"results":{  
           "Description":"",
        },
"service":"",
"eventId":"",
"assetType":"" 
}
```

The second object represents the "Filter Criteria" on that first object. How can I use lodash to return an object that looks like this:

```
var result = {
 "results":{  
     "Description":"There was a record added"
 },
"service":"FDSY",
"eventId":"033dc019-0b8a-4af22",
"assetType":"CLCI" 
}
```

Essentially, I need the result to be only the key value pairs that match the keys in the filter object. I also need to filter on the nested objects

I don't need to use lodash but I know a lot of their features would make this easy.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the keys of filter, [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for iterating the keys and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for assembling the object.

```js
var data = { service: "FDSY", StartTimestamp: "2017-03-23T21:55:17Z", eventId: "033dc019-0b8a-4af22", assetId: "TenGigE0/14/0/0.55", assetType: "CLCI" },
    filter = { service: "", eventId: "", assetType: "" },
    result = Object.keys(filter).reduce((r, k) => Object.assign(r, { [k]: data[k] }), {});

console.log(result);
```

ES5

```js
var data = { service: "FDSY", StartTimestamp: "2017-03-23T21:55:17Z", eventId: "033dc019-0b8a-4af22", assetId: "TenGigE0/14/0/0.55", assetType: "CLCI" },
    filter = { service: "", eventId: "", assetType: "" },
    result = Object.keys(filter).reduce(function (r, k) {
        r[k] = data[k];
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

For deep nested object, you could use an recursive approach with a closure over the source object.

```js
var data = { results: { Description: "There was a record added", resultTimestamp: "2017-03-23T21:56:05Z", foo: {bar:42} }, service: "FDSY", StartTimestamp: "2017-03-23T21:55:17Z", eventId: "033dc019-0b8a-4af22", assetId: "TenGigE0/14/0/0.55", assetType: "CLCI" },
    filter = { results: { Description: "", foo: { bar: "" } }, service: "", eventId: "", assetType: "" },
    result = Object.keys(filter).reduce(function iter(source) {
        return function (r, k) {
            r[k] = filter[k] && typeof filter[k] === 'object' ?
                Object.keys(filter[k]).reduce(iter(source[k]), {}) :
                source[k];
            return r;
        };
    }(data), {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked great. What if there is a nested object?